# What constitutes a transaction in Bing Autosuggest API?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, autosuggest

The [Bing Autosuggest API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/autosuggest/) lists charges as being per transaction like this:

> Features: Up to 100 transactions per second;
>   Unit: Transactions;
>   Price: $3 per 10,000 transactions

But nowhere in the documentation or FAQ does it define what constitutes a transaction.  Can someone clarify what is considered a transaction?  Is one transaction equal to one API call?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, a transaction would be any call to the AutoSuggest API. The only caveats to that look to be the Text Analytics and Recommendations APIs that are stated in the FAQ at the bottom of the [documentation page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/autosuggest-api/).

Answer (score 1):

1 transaction is equal to 1 call for the metric: calls (or transactions) per second. However, for pricing 1 transaction is equal to 1 successful call (response code: 200).